# How to insert multiple records in one stored procedure and rollback if one fails - mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a stored procedure that createAssesments and createAssesmentMarks for students of that particular section.

Whenever I insert single records it executed successfully but when I try to insert multiple records at one as "Subquery returns more than one-row" error and stores data in assesmentsTable , but not the AssesmentMarksTable

So my questions are :

1. How can I insert multiple records at one execution?
2. How can I rollback if something fails to prevent inconsistent data storage?

```
       DELIMITER $$
    
        CREATE PROCEDURE createAssesment(IN name VARCHAR(100), maxMarks INT, classId INT, sectionId INT , subjectId INT)
    
        BEGIN
    
        INSERT INTO assesments (name , maxMarks , classId , sectionId , subjectId) VALUES (name , maxMarks, classId , sectionId , subjectId);
        
        INSERT INTO assesmentMarks  (assesmentId , scoredMarks , studentId) VALUES (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM assesments) , (scoredMarks) ,(SELECT stud.studentId FROM students stud WHERE stud.sectionId = sectionId); 
    
     
        END $$
    
        DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hint: Multi-insert + transaction block.

Comment: hey thanks do u mind giving some futher instructions please ?

Comment: Those keywords will lead you directly to the answers you need.

Comment: thanks brother the hint helped me alot and i will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks @tadman for the hint**

**After some research I found these as an answer to above two questions:-**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createAssesment(IN name VARCHAR(100), maxMarks INT, classId INT, sectionId INT , subjectId INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;  -- rollback any changes made in the transaction
    END;
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION ;
INSERT INTO assesments (name , maxMarks , classId , sectionId , subjectId) VALUES (name , maxMarks , classId , sectionId , subjectId);
INSERT INTO assesmentMarks  (assesmentId  , studentId )
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() , stud.studentId  FROM assesments a CROSS JOIN Students stud WHERE stud.sectionId = sectionId;
COMMIT ;
SET autocommit = 1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```